# Get IDs of unselected rows in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, selection, rows

I'm completely stuck with this. I have a kendo grid where all rows are selected  by "select all" button and some rows can be unselected. So I need to get exactly the IDs of unselected rows.

There is an easy way to get selected rows as grid.select(), but could there be a way to distinguish unselected ones? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

filter rows based on css class 'k-state-selected'. Rows without this class are not selected for sure :-)

$("#xyzGrid > .k-grid-content tr").not($(".k-state-selected"))